# Django -- Views MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I want to return 4 different versions of the homepage

1. Homepage with search bar. No data present from API
   [image]
2. Homepage with search bar. Data present from API 
   [image]
3. Homepage with search bar. No data present if request doesn't exist in API
4. Homepage with search bar. No data present if submit button is hit without any data being entered.

Version two, three and four all work.
However version 1, the homepage without a GET request is not returned. Due to:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at / 'city'" in the views.py file.

How can this be resolved? Any help will be greatly appreciated

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def index(request):
    # Query API with user input 
    payload = {'q': request.GET['city'], 'appid': 'API-KEY'}
    response = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', params=payload)

    # successful request
    if response.status_code == 200:

        # Parse json output for key value pairs 
        e = response.json()

        context = {
            'city_name': e['name'], 
            'weather':e['weather'][0]['main'],
            'description' : e['weather'][0]['description'],
            'temp' : e['main']['temp'],
            'pressure':e['main']['pressure'],
            'humidity':e['main']['humidity'],
            'visibility':e['visibility'],
            'wind_speed':e['wind']['speed'],
            'wind_deg':e['wind']['deg']
            }


        return render(request, 'index.html', {'context': context}) 
    

    else: # returns homepage if invalid city name is given in form
            return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `request.GET['city']` directly, check if city is set first, like:

```
if 'city' in request.GET:
    payload = {'q': request.GET['city'], 'appid': 'API-KEY'}
```